# how to unregister all dependencies with Get_it in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using get_it to register my dependencies in my app.
I register them like this.

```
locator.registerLazySingleton<OnBoardingController>(() => Get.put(
      OnBoardingController(locator(), locator(), locator(), locator())));
  locator.registerLazySingleton<SurveyController>(
      () => Get.put(SurveyController(locator(), locator())));
  locator.registerLazySingleton<OnBoardingAnswerController>(
      () => Get.put(OnBoardingAnswerController(locator())));
```

and there is bunch of code like this.
I want to unregister them all and register them again. how can I achieve that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset my controller when I come back or finish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66292416/how-do-i-reset-my-controller-when-i-come-back-or-finish)

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67250736/flutter-getx-how-to-remove-initialized-controller-every-time-we-navigate-to-oth

Comment: @OMiShah No it does not because they both are related to Getx but my problem is with get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `locator.reset();`

This is from the documentation:

```
Future<void> reset({bool dispose = true});
```

Clears all registered types. Handy when writing unit tests

If you provided dispose function when registering they will be called

[dispose] if `false` it only resets without calling any dispose functions

As dispose funcions can be async, you should await this function.

Comment: duplicate quest !

Comment: What didn't work? Did you set `allowReassignment = true`?